# All of a sudden, I cannot change any strings in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio

I am using the Google+ API and trying to add Chat to my application (Not run chat using Google). The chat part is easy, yet I can't change my strings to add a backslash before an apostrophe all of a sudden. Plus, it has added `<resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">`, and I do not know why that is there nor what it means.

My strings.xml file (not entire file):

```
<!-- Top of file -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">


<string name="common_android_wear_notification_needs_update_text"><ns1:g id="app_name">%1$s</ns1:g> requires an update to the Android Wear app.</string>
<string name="common_android_wear_update_text"><ns1:g id="app_name">%1$s</ns1:g> won\'t run unless you update the Android Wear app.</string>
<string msgid="6006316683626838685" name="common_android_wear_update_title">Update Android Wear</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_api_unavailable_text"><ns1:g id="app_name">%1$s</ns1:g> requires one or more Google Play services that are not currently available. Please contact the developer for assistance.</string>
<string msgid="2523291102206661146" name="common_google_play_services_enable_button">Enable Google Play services</string>
<string msgid="227660514972886228" name="common_google_play_services_enable_text"><ns1:g id="app_name">%1$s</ns1:g> won\'t work unless you enable Google Play services.</string>
<string msgid="5122002158466380389" name="common_google_play_services_enable_title">Enable Google Play services</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_error_notification_requested_by_msg">Requested by <ns1:g id="app_name">%1$s</ns1:g></string>
<string msgid="7153882981874058840" name="common_google_play_services_install_button">Get Google Play services</string>
<string msgid="2122112764540849864" name="common_google_play_services_install_text_phone"><ns1:g id="app_name">%1$s</ns1:g> won\'t run without Google Play services, which are missing from your phone.</string>
<string msgid="7351599665250191022" name="common_google_play_services_install_text_tablet"><ns1:g id="app_name">%1$s</ns1:g> won\'t run without Google Play services, which are missing from your tablet.</string>
<string msgid="7215213145546190223" name="common_google_play_services_install_title">Get Google Play services</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_invalid_account_text">The specified account does not exist on this device. Please choose a different account.</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_invalid_account_title">Invalid Account</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_needs_enabling_title">An application requires Google Play services to be enabled.</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_network_error_text">A data connection is required to connect to Google Play services.</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_network_error_title">Network Error</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_notification_needs_update_title">An application requires an update for Google Play services.</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_notification_ticker">Google Play services error</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_sign_in_failed_text">Error signing in the specified account. Please choose a different account.</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_sign_in_failed_title">Sign in failed</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_unknown_issue">Unknown issue with Google Play services.</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_unsupported_text"><ns1:g id="app_name">%1$s</ns1:g> relies on Google Play services, which is not supported by your device. Contact the manufacturer for assistance.</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_unsupported_title">Google Play services</string>
<string msgid="6556509956452265614" name="common_google_play_services_update_button">Update</string>
<string msgid="9053896323427875356" name="common_google_play_services_update_text"><ns1:g id="app_name">%1$s</ns1:g> won\'t run unless you update Google Play services.</string>
<string msgid="6006316683626838685" name="common_google_play_services_update_title">Update Google Play services</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_updating_text"><ns1:g id="app_name">%1$s</ns1:g> won\'t run without Google Play services, which are currently updating.</string>
<string name="common_google_play_services_updating_title">Google Play services are updating</string>
<string name="common_open_on_phone">Open on phone</string>
<string name="common_signin_button_text">Sign in</string>
<string name="common_signin_button_text_long">Sign in with Google</string>
<string name="disk_cache_description">On Ice Cream Sandwich and above, a disk cache is
automatically used so that subsequent requests for the same URL do not re-download the
image.\n\nTo enable this functionality on pre-ICS use a standalone HTTP client with caching such
as OkHttp.
</string>
<string name="easter_egg">I am an easter egg!</string>
<string name="edit">Edit</string>
<string name="email">Email</string>
<string name="err_fields_empty">Please fill all the fields.</string>
<string name="err_login">Error occurred while login:</string>
<string name="err_singup">Error occurred while signup:</string>
<string name="err_users">Error occurred while finding users:</string>
<string name="error_a">Error with Activity</string>
<string name="error_b">Unable to launch the specified Activity or the link was to this page. Check back later.</string>
<string name="error_field_required">This field is required</string>
<string name="error_incorrect_password">This password is incorrect</string>
<string name="error_invalid_email">This email address is invalid</string>
<string name="error_invalid_password">This password is too short</string>
<string name="fetch_content_base">Fetching content. Please wait.</string>
<string name="forgot_my_pwd">I can't remember my password!</string>
```

The `forgot_my_pwd` string has the apostrophe and I have tried to add the backslash, but whenever I build, compile, or clean, it will delete the changes and say `Error:(307) Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in I can't remember my password!)`. This barely happened while adding a couple strings, and I don't think that should change anything.  Any help is appreciated as I have run out of clues on how to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: um i think you are working with the wrong strings.xml file. The Google Play services <!--Google Play generated stuff--> seems really suspicious in this file...

Comment: I put that on there. Not in the actual code.

Comment: but why do you have those strings at all? adding the compile line to your gradle file should give you all of these resources automatically...

Comment: I hit build and it put all of these strings on there, now I cannot get them off nor can I even edit the file.

Comment: where is this strings file located?

Comment: strings.xml « values « res

Comment: Are you sure you are editing that exact file in that location? Mouse over the tab and verify the path. Also if it is one of the non project files I believe Android Studio colors the tab a bit differently.

Comment: Ah, ok. it is a light yellow. Ok it works now Thanks very much!

Comment: this happened to me too :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted this answer for any viewers that are experiencing this same problem. All of these steps are explained in the comments for the main post, but here are the steps rewritten:

First, check to see if the `strings.xml` or `values.xml` file that you are viewing is not the system one. To tell if it is the system one, the tab for the file will be a light yellow color, as shown below.

[image: Light yellow values.xml file tab]

If it is equivalent to the image shown, then it is a build file, and it cannot be edited.

To navigate to the editable file, make sure the view on the file tree is set to 'Android' here:

[image: Dropdown menu image]

Now, navigate to the file circled in the file browser as shown in the following image:

[image: File tree strings.xml image]

Once you have navigated to this file, you should be able to change the values of the string that you desire.